# building and hosting vendor bundle separately

Tags: angular, webpack, cdn, webpack-2

**Usecase/Requirement/Problem:**
host vendor and polyfills bundle separately in CDN so that they can be reused across multiple angular2 apps. The vendor and polyfills bundle will be build as a separate angular2 app using webpack 2 and resultant bundles will be hosted in a CDN and reused by N angular2 apps.

**What am i upto ?**
Have created a good size ang2 project with webpack using starter project from  [angular2 webpack2 starter](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter), build using prod mode, runs fine.
We have an internal CDN so we decided to host vendor and pollyfills separately and too which can be reused by other angular2 projects when hosted.
Have created a ang2 project that specifically builds vendor and polyfills

**What did i Code ?**
Basically i believe i am messing somewhere in webpack configuration.
This is my webpack.common.js from good sized angular2 project

```
    /**
 * @author: @AngularClass
 */

const webpack = require('webpack');
const helpers = require('./helpers');

/*
 * Webpack Plugins
 */
// problem with copy-webpack-plugin
const AssetsPlugin = require('assets-webpack-plugin');
const NormalModuleReplacementPlugin = require('webpack/lib/NormalModuleReplacementPlugin');
const ContextReplacementPlugin = require('webpack/lib/ContextReplacementPlugin');
const CommonsChunkPlugin = require('webpack/lib/optimize/CommonsChunkPlugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const CheckerPlugin = require('awesome-typescript-loader').CheckerPlugin;
const HtmlElementsPlugin = require('./html-elements-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const LoaderOptionsPlugin = require('webpack/lib/LoaderOptionsPlugin');
const ScriptExtHtmlWebpackPlugin = require('script-ext-html-webpack-plugin');
const ngcWebpack = require('ngc-webpack');

/*
 * Webpack Constants
 */
const HMR = helpers.hasProcessFlag('hot');
const AOT = helpers.hasNpmFlag('aot');
const METADATA = {
  title: 'Angular2 Webpack Starter by @gdi2290 from @AngularClass',
  baseUrl: '/',
  isDevServer: helpers.isWebpackDevServer()
};

/*
 * Webpack configuration
 *
 * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#cli
 */
module.exports = function (options) {
  isProd = options.env === 'production';
  return {

    recordsInputPath: 'webpack-module-records.json',
    /*
     * Cache generated modules and chunks to improve performance for multiple incremental builds.
     * This is enabled by default in watch mode.
     * You can pass false to disable it.
     *
     * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#cache
     */
    //cache: false,

    /*
     * The entry point for the bundle
     * Our Angular.js app
     *
     * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#entry
     */
    entry: {

      'polyfills': './src/polyfills.browser.ts',
      'vendor': './src/vendor.browser.ts',
      'main': AOT ? './src/main.browser.aot.ts' :
        './src/main.browser.ts'

    },

    /*
     * Options affecting the resolving of modules.
     *
     * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve
     */
    resolve: {

      /*
       * An array of extensions that should be used to resolve modules.
       *
       * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-extensions
       */
      extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.json'],

      // An array of directory names to be resolved to the current directory
      modules: [helpers.root('src'), helpers.root('node_modules')],

    },

    /*
     * Options affecting the normal modules.
     *
     * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#module
     */
    module: {

      rules: [

        /*
         * Typescript loader support for .ts and Angular 2 async routes via .async.ts
         * Replace templateUrl and stylesUrl with require()
         *
         * See: https://github.com/s-panferov/awesome-typescript-loader
         * See: https://github.com/TheLarkInn/angular2-template-loader
         */
        {
          test: /\.ts$/,
          use: [
            '@angularclass/hmr-loader?pretty=' + !isProd + '&prod=' + isProd,
            'awesome-typescript-loader?{configFileName: "tsconfig.webpack.json"}',
            'angular2-template-loader',
            {
              loader: 'ng-router-loader',
              options: {
                loader: 'async-system',
                genDir: 'compiled',
                aot: AOT
              }
            }
          ],
          exclude: [/\.(spec|e2e)\.ts$/]
        },

        /*
         * Json loader support for *.json files.
         *
         * See: https://github.com/webpack/json-loader
         */
        {
          test: /\.json$/,
          use: 'json-loader'
        },

        /*
         * to string and css loader support for *.css files (from Angular components)
         * Returns file content as string
         *
         */
        {
          test: /\.css$/,
          use: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader'],
          exclude: [helpers.root('src', 'styles')]
        },

        /*
         * to string and sass loader support for *.scss files (from Angular components)
         * Returns compiled css content as string
         *
         */
        {
          test: /\.scss$/,
          use: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
          exclude: [helpers.root('src', 'styles')]
        },

        /* Raw loader support for *.html
         * Returns file content as string
         *
         * See: https://github.com/webpack/raw-loader
         */
        {
          test: /\.html$/,
          use: 'raw-loader',
          exclude: [helpers.root('src/index.html')]
        },

        /* File loader for supporting images, for example, in CSS files.
         */
        {
          test: /\.(jpg|png|gif)$/,
          use: 'file-loader'
        },

      ],

    },

    /*
     * Add additional plugins to the compiler.
     *
     * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#plugins
     */
    plugins: [
      new AssetsPlugin({
        path: helpers.root('dist'),
        filename: 'webpack-assets.json',
        prettyPrint: true
      }),

      /*
       * Plugin: ForkCheckerPlugin
       * Description: Do type checking in a separate process, so webpack don't need to wait.
       *
       * See: https://github.com/s-panferov/awesome-typescript-loader#forkchecker-boolean-defaultfalse
       */
      new CheckerPlugin(),
      /*
       * Plugin: CommonsChunkPlugin
       * Description: Shares common code between the pages.
       * It identifies common modules and put them into a commons chunk.
       *
       * See: https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#commonschunkplugin
       * See: https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/optimization#multi-page-app
       */

      // This enables tree shaking of the vendor modules
      new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name: ['app', 'vendor', 'polyfills'],
        minChunks: Infinity
      }),

      /**
       * Plugin: ContextReplacementPlugin
       * Description: Provides context to Angular's use of System.import
       *
       * See: https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#contextreplacementplugin
       * See: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11580
       */
      new ContextReplacementPlugin(
        // The (\\|\/) piece accounts for path separators in *nix and Windows
        /angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)src(\\|\/)linker/,
        helpers.root('src'), // location of your src
        {
          // your Angular Async Route paths relative to this root directory
        }
      ),

      /*
       * Plugin: CopyWebpackPlugin
       * Description: Copy files and directories in webpack.
       *
       * Copies project static assets.
       *
       * See: https://www.npmjs.com/package/copy-webpack-plugin
       */
      new CopyWebpackPlugin([
        { from: 'src/assets', to: 'assets' },
        { from: 'src/meta' }
      ]),


      /*
       * Plugin: HtmlWebpackPlugin
       * Description: Simplifies creation of HTML files to serve your webpack bundles.
       * This is especially useful for webpack bundles that include a hash in the filename
       * which changes every compilation.
       *
       * See: https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin
       */
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: 'src/index.html',
        title: METADATA.title,
        chunksSortMode: 'dependency',
        metadata: METADATA,
        inject: 'head'
      }),

      /*
       * Plugin: ScriptExtHtmlWebpackPlugin
       * Description: Enhances html-webpack-plugin functionality
       * with different deployment options for your scripts including:
       *
       * See: https://github.com/numical/script-ext-html-webpack-plugin
       */
      new ScriptExtHtmlWebpackPlugin({
        defaultAttribute: 'defer'
      }),

      /*
       * Plugin: HtmlElementsPlugin
       * Description: Generate html tags based on javascript maps.
       *
       * If a publicPath is set in the webpack output configuration, it will be automatically added to
       * href attributes, you can disable that by adding a "=href": false property.
       * You can also enable it to other attribute by settings "=attName": true.
       *
       * The configuration supplied is map between a location (key) and an element definition object (value)
       * The location (key) is then exported to the template under then htmlElements property in webpack configuration.
       *
       * Example:
       *  Adding this plugin configuration
       *  new HtmlElementsPlugin({
       *    headTags: { ... }
       *  })
       *
       *  Means we can use it in the template like this:
       *  <%= webpackConfig.htmlElements.headTags %>
       *
       * Dependencies: HtmlWebpackPlugin
       */
      new HtmlElementsPlugin({
        headTags: require('./head-config.common')
      }),

      /**
       * Plugin LoaderOptionsPlugin (experimental)
       *
       * See: https://gist.github.com/sokra/27b24881210b56bbaff7
       */
      new LoaderOptionsPlugin({}),

      // Fix Angular 2
      new NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(
        /facade(\\|\/)async/,
        helpers.root('node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/async.js')
      ),
      new NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(
        /facade(\\|\/)collection/,
        helpers.root('node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.js')
      ),
      new NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(
        /facade(\\|\/)errors/,
        helpers.root('node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/errors.js')
      ),
      new NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(
        /facade(\\|\/)lang/,
        helpers.root('node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/lang.js')
      ),
      new NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(
        /facade(\\|\/)math/,
        helpers.root('node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/math.js')
      ),

      new ngcWebpack.NgcWebpackPlugin({
        disabled: !AOT,
        tsConfig: helpers.root('tsconfig.webpack.json'),
        resourceOverride: helpers.root('config/resource-override.js')
      })

    ],

    /*
     * Include polyfills or mocks for various node stuff
     * Description: Node configuration
     *
     * See: https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#node
     */
    node: {
      global: true,
      crypto: 'empty',
      process: true,
      module: false,
      clearImmediate: false,
      setImmediate: false
    }

  };
}
```

Below is my common config from ang2 project that builds vendor and polyfills

```
    /**
 * @author: @AngularClass
 */

const webpack = require('webpack');
const helpers = require('./helpers');

/*
 * Webpack Plugins
 */
// problem with copy-webpack-plugin
const AssetsPlugin = require('assets-webpack-plugin');
const NormalModuleReplacementPlugin = require('webpack/lib/NormalModuleReplacementPlugin');
const ContextReplacementPlugin = require('webpack/lib/ContextReplacementPlugin');
const CommonsChunkPlugin = require('webpack/lib/optimize/CommonsChunkPlugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const CheckerPlugin = require('awesome-typescript-loader').CheckerPlugin;
const HtmlElementsPlugin = require('./html-elements-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const LoaderOptionsPlugin = require('webpack/lib/LoaderOptionsPlugin');
const ScriptExtHtmlWebpackPlugin = require('script-ext-html-webpack-plugin');
const ngcWebpack = require('ngc-webpack');

/*
 * Webpack Constants
 */
const HMR = helpers.hasProcessFlag('hot');
const AOT = helpers.hasNpmFlag('aot');
const METADATA = {
  title: 'Angular2 Webpack Starter by @gdi2290 from @AngularClass',
  baseUrl: '/',
  isDevServer: helpers.isWebpackDevServer()
};

/*
 * Webpack configuration
 *
 * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#cli
 */
module.exports = function (options) {
  isProd = options.env === 'production';
  return {

    recordsInputPath: 'webpack-module-records.json',
    /*
     * Cache generated modules and chunks to improve performance for multiple incremental builds.
     * This is enabled by default in watch mode.
     * You can pass false to disable it.
     *
     * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#cache
     */
    //cache: false,

    /*
     * The entry point for the bundle
     * Our Angular.js app
     *
     * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#entry
     */
    entry: {

      'polyfills': './src/polyfills.browser.ts',
      'vendor': './src/vendor.browser.ts',
      'main': AOT ? './src/main.browser.aot.ts' :
        './src/main.browser.ts'

    },

    /*
     * Options affecting the resolving of modules.
     *
     * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve
     */
    resolve: {

      /*
       * An array of extensions that should be used to resolve modules.
       *
       * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-extensions
       */
      extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.json'],

      // An array of directory names to be resolved to the current directory
      modules: [helpers.root('src'), helpers.root('node_modules')],

    },

    /*
     * Options affecting the normal modules.
     *
     * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#module
     */
    module: {

      rules: [

        /*
         * Typescript loader support for .ts and Angular 2 async routes via .async.ts
         * Replace templateUrl and stylesUrl with require()
         *
         * See: https://github.com/s-panferov/awesome-typescript-loader
         * See: https://github.com/TheLarkInn/angular2-template-loader
         */
        {
          test: /\.ts$/,
          use: [
            '@angularclass/hmr-loader?pretty=' + !isProd + '&prod=' + isProd,
            'awesome-typescript-loader?{configFileName: "tsconfig.webpack.json"}',
            'angular2-template-loader',
            {
              loader: 'ng-router-loader',
              options: {
                loader: 'async-system',
                genDir: 'compiled',
                aot: AOT
              }
            }
          ],
          exclude: [/\.(spec|e2e)\.ts$/]
        },

        /*
         * Json loader support for *.json files.
         *
         * See: https://github.com/webpack/json-loader
         */
        {
          test: /\.json$/,
          use: 'json-loader'
        },

        /*
         * to string and css loader support for *.css files (from Angular components)
         * Returns file content as string
         *
         */
        {
          test: /\.css$/,
          use: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader'],
          exclude: [helpers.root('src', 'styles')]
        },

        /*
         * to string and sass loader support for *.scss files (from Angular components)
         * Returns compiled css content as string
         *
         */
        {
          test: /\.scss$/,
          use: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
          exclude: [helpers.root('src', 'styles')]
        },

        /* Raw loader support for *.html
         * Returns file content as string
         *
         * See: https://github.com/webpack/raw-loader
         */
        {
          test: /\.html$/,
          use: 'raw-loader',
          exclude: [helpers.root('src/index.html')]
        },

        /* File loader for supporting images, for example, in CSS files.
         */
        {
          test: /\.(jpg|png|gif)$/,
          use: 'file-loader'
        },

      ],

    },

    /*
     * Add additional plugins to the compiler.
     *
     * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#plugins
     */
    plugins: [
      new AssetsPlugin({
        path: helpers.root('dist'),
        filename: 'webpack-assets.json',
        prettyPrint: true
      }),

      /*
       * Plugin: ForkCheckerPlugin
       * Description: Do type checking in a separate process, so webpack don't need to wait.
       *
       * See: https://github.com/s-panferov/awesome-typescript-loader#forkchecker-boolean-defaultfalse
       */
      new CheckerPlugin(),
      /*
       * Plugin: CommonsChunkPlugin
       * Description: Shares common code between the pages.
       * It identifies common modules and put them into a commons chunk.
       *
       * See: https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#commonschunkplugin
       * See: https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/optimization#multi-page-app
       */

      // This enables tree shaking of the vendor modules
      new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name: ['app', 'vendor', 'polyfills'],
        minChunks: Infinity
      }),

      /**
       * Plugin: ContextReplacementPlugin
       * Description: Provides context to Angular's use of System.import
       *
       * See: https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#contextreplacementplugin
       * See: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11580
       */
      new ContextReplacementPlugin(
        // The (\\|\/) piece accounts for path separators in *nix and Windows
        /angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)src(\\|\/)linker/,
        helpers.root('src'), // location of your src
        {
          // your Angular Async Route paths relative to this root directory
        }
      ),

      /*
       * Plugin: CopyWebpackPlugin
       * Description: Copy files and directories in webpack.
       *
       * Copies project static assets.
       *
       * See: https://www.npmjs.com/package/copy-webpack-plugin
       */
      new CopyWebpackPlugin([
        { from: 'src/assets', to: 'assets' },
        { from: 'src/meta' }
      ]),


      /*
       * Plugin: HtmlWebpackPlugin
       * Description: Simplifies creation of HTML files to serve your webpack bundles.
       * This is especially useful for webpack bundles that include a hash in the filename
       * which changes every compilation.
       *
       * See: https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin
       */
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: 'src/index.html',
        title: METADATA.title,
        chunksSortMode: 'dependency',
        metadata: METADATA,
        inject: 'head'
      }),

      /*
       * Plugin: ScriptExtHtmlWebpackPlugin
       * Description: Enhances html-webpack-plugin functionality
       * with different deployment options for your scripts including:
       *
       * See: https://github.com/numical/script-ext-html-webpack-plugin
       */
      new ScriptExtHtmlWebpackPlugin({
        defaultAttribute: 'defer'
      }),

      /*
       * Plugin: HtmlElementsPlugin
       * Description: Generate html tags based on javascript maps.
       *
       * If a publicPath is set in the webpack output configuration, it will be automatically added to
       * href attributes, you can disable that by adding a "=href": false property.
       * You can also enable it to other attribute by settings "=attName": true.
       *
       * The configuration supplied is map between a location (key) and an element definition object (value)
       * The location (key) is then exported to the template under then htmlElements property in webpack configuration.
       *
       * Example:
       *  Adding this plugin configuration
       *  new HtmlElementsPlugin({
       *    headTags: { ... }
       *  })
       *
       *  Means we can use it in the template like this:
       *  <%= webpackConfig.htmlElements.headTags %>
       *
       * Dependencies: HtmlWebpackPlugin
       */
      new HtmlElementsPlugin({
        headTags: require('./head-config.common')
      }),

      /**
       * Plugin LoaderOptionsPlugin (experimental)
       *
       * See: https://gist.github.com/sokra/27b24881210b56bbaff7
       */
      new LoaderOptionsPlugin({}),

      // Fix Angular 2
      new NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(
        /facade(\\|\/)async/,
        helpers.root('node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/async.js')
      ),
      new NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(
        /facade(\\|\/)collection/,
        helpers.root('node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.js')
      ),
      new NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(
        /facade(\\|\/)errors/,
        helpers.root('node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/errors.js')
      ),
      new NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(
        /facade(\\|\/)lang/,
        helpers.root('node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/lang.js')
      ),
      new NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(
        /facade(\\|\/)math/,
        helpers.root('node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/math.js')
      ),

      new ngcWebpack.NgcWebpackPlugin({
        disabled: !AOT,
        tsConfig: helpers.root('tsconfig.webpack.json'),
        resourceOverride: helpers.root('config/resource-override.js')
      })

    ],

    /*
     * Include polyfills or mocks for various node stuff
     * Description: Node configuration
     *
     * See: https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#node
     */
    node: {
      global: true,
      crypto: 'empty',
      process: true,
      module: false,
      clearImmediate: false,
      setImmediate: false
    }

  };
}
```

TL;DR - points to observe in above configs are recordsPath, entryPoints, CommonsChunkPlugin. Rest config is unchanged and taken directly from starter pack mentioned above.

When run separatly good sized angular2 project runs fine, when I deploy my project with local main js, and remote vendor and pollyfills, See below the way i reference it in index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/cdn/dist/a2-bundle/polyfills.bundle.js" defer></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/cdn/dist/a2-bundle/vendor.bundle.js" defer></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/ng2/dist/main.bundle.js" defer></script>
```

I get error in browser.

```
    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '_console' of undefined
    at t (vendor.bundle.js:19)
    at Object.984 (main.bundle.js:1)
    at n (polyfills.bundle.js:1)
    at Object.990 (main.bundle.js:1)
    at n (polyfills.bundle.js:1)
    at Object.988 (main.bundle.js:1)
    at n (polyfills.bundle.js:1)
    at Object.1013 (main.bundle.js:1)
    at n (polyfills.bundle.js:1)
    at window.webpackJsonp (polyfills.bundle.js:1)
    at main.bundle.js:1
```

I have searched over internet to make this working but unable to do so.
Since webpack provides a unique id for every modules while building bundles, I have used records Path here in configuration.

What do you suggest?
Any other alternative/solution is most welcomed by me

Thank you........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For such type of usecase i was surely going in wrong direction.
DLLPlugin (at CDN) and DLLReferencePlugin (at client end) solved my problem.